# Can't figure out how to generate subsampling view in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a view that generates this data:

```
ps_id  min                     max
5017   2016-07-18 22:28:25     2016-07-19 06:23:17
5018   2016-07-18 18:29:06     2016-07-18 18:40:05
5019   2016-07-18 23:31:21     2016-07-19 00:10:07
```

The view I'm trying to create should do the following. It should take the "min" value for a given ps_id above, and it should find the top of the hour. Take the min from the first row above for example:

```
2016-07-18 22:28:25 --> 2016-07-18 22:00:00
```

The same thing should happen for the "max" value in the first row from above:

```
2016-07-19 06:23:17 --> 2016-07-19 06:00:00
```

Then, I need the view to generate the sub-series that fills in all the gaps between the generated "min" and "max" values, which in this case would be generating all the tops of the hour between the "min" top of the hour:

```
2016-07-18 22:00:00
```

and the "max" top of the hour:

```
2016-07-19 06:00:00
```

At the end of all of this, I need the view to generate this for each ps_id, and it should look like this:

```
ps_id           hour_segment
5017            2016-07-18 22:00:00
5017            2016-07-18 23:00:00
5017            2016-07-19 00:00:00
5017            2016-07-19 01:00:00
5017            2016-07-19 02:00:00
5017            2016-07-19 03:00:00
5017            2016-07-19 04:00:00
5017            2016-07-19 05:00:00
5017            2016-07-19 06:00:00
5018            2016-07-18 18:00:00
5019            2016-07-18 23:00:00
5019            2016-07-19 00:00:00
```

I have been beating my head against this one for far too long, and really need some brilliant minds that know what they're doing in MySQL to provide some insight here.

Help!

Comment: What do the results have to do with the sample data?  How do you get the time values?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like a simple `group by`:

```
create view v_table as
    select ps_id, min(hour_segment) as `min`, max(hour_segment) as `max`
    from t
    group by ps_id;
```

However, this doesn't produce the results in your question.  It is unclear what the relationship is between the sample data and desired results.

Comment: Yeah, I can see how from my original post it would seem like that's the case. Unfortunately, it isn't as simple as what you've suggested. I've updated it to better reflect what I'm trying to do.